# How can I easily define more complex PartialFunctions in Scala?

Tags: scala, lift, partialfunction

### PartialFunctions

In Scala, a [`PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) is, in short, a function that additionally defines an `isDefinedAt` method.

It is easy to define partial functions with a series of `case` statement. A trivial example would be, e.g.:

```
scala> val pf: PartialFunction[Int, Unit] = {
     | case 42 => ()
     | }
pf: PartialFunction[Int,Unit] = <function1>

scala> pf.isDefinedAt(42)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> pf.isDefinedAt(0) 
res1: Boolean = false
```

`isDefinedAt` is automatically generated from the list of `case`s defining the partial function.

### Context

The Lift framework makes use of partial functions in many places, e.g. to define whether a request should be processed by Lift's engine or served directly from a file on disk, as is. and sometimes, I find myself wanting to write a `case` statement that matches all input parameters and only later decide if I want to return a value or not. This means that the initial series of `case`s is not enough any more to determine if my function is defined at a given value or not

For instance, in Lift, I want to add a rule that all html and htm files are served directly, and that files with the “lift” extension should be processed. It would look easy to do something like this:

```
LiftRules.liftRequest.prepend {
  case Req(path, extension, tpe) => extension match {
    case "html" | "htm" => false
    case "lift" => true
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case, the compiler thinks that my partial function is defined everywhere, as the first `case` always matches. It's the nested `match` that may not match all incoming requests. And, is a request is not matched, a `MatchError` is thrown.

### Question

Is there a simple way to make the compiler consider nested `match` statements when defining a partial function, or is the only way to do it to inline all nested conditionals like this?

```
LiftRules.liftRequest.prepend {
  case Req(path, extension, tpe) if extension == "html" || extension == "htm" => false
  case Req(path, extension, tpe) if extension == "lift" => true
}
```

In this example, it's largely doable, but the readability is decreased, and I've faced cases where inlining all checks looks very ugly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In this case, you may want to write

```
LiftRules.liftRequest.prepend {
  case Req(path, "html" | "htm", tpe) => false
  case Req(path, "lift", tpe) => true
}
```

For more complicated cases, you’ll need to define your own extractor which you’ll have to use instead of a nested `case` statement.

```
object CheckExtension {
  def unapply(ext: String) = ext match {
    case "lift" => Some(true)
    case "html" | "htm" => Some(false)
    case _ => None
  }
}

LiftRules.liftRequest.prepend {
  case Req(path, CheckExtension(valid), tpe) => valid
}
```

This will only match if your predefined `unapply` function returns `Some` and assign the value of `Some` to the free variable `valid`. If `unapply` returns `None`, no match is being generated.

Comment: Thanks! Custom extractors are the way to go, then. Nice solution — although it's a bit more difficult to follow what's happening…

Comment: You could write `case Req(path, ext @ CheckExtension(valid), tpe)` instead to explicitly show what `Req` gives you.

Comment: Whoa! I had no idea you could use alternatives inside a pattern extractor. Thanks